# Can one use inconsistent terms in the claims?

Tags: claims

My speciation contains terms like this.

```
The term "Service" means ....
The term "Service Administrator" means ....
```

I have already filed my application. At the moment I'm amending my claims. I think I can't make changes to my specification.

When I word claim like `a service by a service administrator`, the term "a service" appear twice. So it's kind of confusing.

I wanna add hyphens.

So the claim would read like this. `a service by a service-administrator`

Will there be any problem if I use the term that's inconsistent with my specification?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any problem in "a service is a service administrator". If you feel like then referring to "the service administrator" is confusing due to the term "service", then say "the administrator". Unless the examiner is very picky, it is understood that "the administrator" refers to the defined "service administrator".

You could use hyphens as well, but if possible I like to stick to the words of the description as they are because you never know who is going to interpret the claim words such that they do not necessarily refer to the words of the description without hyphen.

Comment: Totally agree. I see no problem this solution. If you are still worried, you can add the spec's reference characters (in parentheses) after the corresponding elements, as discussed in MPEP [608.01(m)](https://mpep.uspto.gov/RDMS/MPEP/E8r8#/E8r8/d0e45061.html)